# requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): # python telegram bot using pytelegrambotapi

Tags: python, proxy, telegram-bot, tor, python-telegram-bot

When I want to connect to telegram bot using Tor that returns error blow

> requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f28923f4a30>, 'Connection to api.telegram.org timed out. (connect timeout=20)'))

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You got this error because of that there is a problem to connect telegram servers directly (due to censorship)! You may need to use a VPN or change your dns provider for using tor with Telegram Bot in Ubuntu.
Just use eny VPN or to use Tor you have to do this:

first install **tor** using `sudo apt install tor`
then run commeds blow

```
sudo apt install privoxy torsocks

nano /etc/privoxy/config
```

then `pip install pysocks` after that uncommnet line that contains  `forward-socks5t / 127.0.0.1:9050 .`

now

```
sudo systemctl enable privoxy.service
sudo systemctl start privoxy.service
```

now make sure that in `/etc/tor/torsocks.conf` file commends blow are uncommnted

```
TorAddress 127.0.0.1
TorPort 9050
```

restart your system

next, add codes blow in your bot source code

```
from telebot import apihelper

apihelper.proxy = {'https': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050',
#    'http':'http://127.0.0.1:8118',
#    'https':'https://127.0.0.1:8118'
}
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN) # be sure telebot.TeleBot calls after apihelper.proxy
```

Note: If you can't connect, just force stop tor and reconnect it by yourself